# How to make session not expire in symfony security system?

Tags: symfony5, php-8.1

I am working on user authentication, which returns following if success. It stores the information in session/cookie which gets expired when inactive. Is there a way to make the session not expire or increase the time ?

```
try {
    return new Passport(
        new UserBadge($this->user->getUsername()),
        new PasswordCredentials($this->user->password)
    );
} catch (Throwable) {
    throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Error');
}
```